# How do I run Asymptote in batch mode, without creating windows?

Tags: asymptote

I am using asymptote to generate lots of images in a LaTeX document. The images are translated from asymptote to PDF as this:

```
pdflatex text.tex
asy text-*.asy
pdflatex text.tex
```

However, asymptote insists in opening a window, (which briefly flashes and goes away, without any content). Because of that I cannot compile my document from a remote machine using ssh:

```
asy x.asy
freeglut (asy): failed to open display ''
```

Is there a way to run asymptote in some mode that does not require a window system (without a defined `DISPLAY` in Unix)?

I have already tried `-noView` and `-nointeractiveView`, but Asymptote will still try to open a window.

Comment: Try `asy -noView text-*.asy`

Comment: egreg: thanks, but even with `-noView` it tries to use the display...

Comment: nordev: it also complains about not being able to "`open display ''`"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Asymptote has disabled offscreen rendering by default. To enable this feature, pass the `-offscreen` option to `asy`:

```
asy -offscreen text-*.asy
```

Alternatively you can create a `config.asy` [configuration file](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/doc/Options.html#configuration-file) and include the following:

```
import settings;
offscreen=true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like things have changed, the first method (`-offscreen`) in the [other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261111/250119) will be interpreted as `-o ffscreen` i.e. output to a file named `ffscreen.eps` or `ffscreen.pdf`.

The second method `settings.offscreen` just doesn't work.

One option is to build asymptote from source with `--enable-offscreen` instead .

Unfortunately, for me, offscreen OSMesa has some unknown issue -- https://github.com/vectorgraphics/asymptote/issues/392 has the detail.

So, another option is to run a headless/virtual X server.

- First, run `Xvfb :1` to start a virtual X server, listen for connections at server number 1.
- Then, tell Asymptote which display to use: `DISPLAY=:1 asy a.asy` or `asy --glOptions="-display :1" a.asy` both works.

Remark: the (not very well-documented) option `-glOptions` pass the options to [`glutInit()`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node10.html).

Note that [`Xvfb` appears to not use GPU, so rendering can be slower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65870117/how-to-run-multiple-applications-that-need-x-server-in-headless-ubuntu-server). You may also take a look at https://superuser.com/a/503355/577463 for other options of headless X servers.